# How can I use bitmap fonts in gvim?

Tags: fonts, vim, text-editor

When doing actual work, I can't stand the scalable monospaced fonts that are available to me with the default install.  How can I make gVim use the good old 6x13 x11 font?

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
rm 70-no-bitmaps.conf
ln -s ../conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf .
```

And then restart X, or do a `fc-cache -f`.

Comment: I did this, but I still can't seem to see the fonts from xfonts-base appear in font selection dialog boxes.

Comment: Try to install xfonts-75dpi or -100dpi as well. Also, you could check xlsfonts and/or xfontsel for the installed bitmap fonts.

Comment: you could try linking to 70-force-bitmaps instead. 70-yes-bitmaps doesn't have anything in it on my machine.