# How can I activate bitmap fonts?

Tags: 11.10, fonts

I need to use pcf fonts but it seems that they are disabled now. I followed [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6710/how-can-i-use-bitmap-fonts-in-gvim) without success. (both `70-yes-bitmaps.conf` and `-bitmaps`)

The fonts are visible with `xfontsel` but the app can't see/use them. Any idea?

It used to work with Ubuntu 10.10 but I installed 11.10 now so I suspect GNOME 3 or Unity because there is no problem with KDE.

Answer (score 4):

Try linking to `70-force-bitmaps` instead. `70-yes-bitmaps` doesn't seem to have anything in it.  (This is taken from [your link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6710/how-can-i-use-bitmap-fonts-in-gvim).)  This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

The process is like this (Added by a user on 14.04)

```
sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-force-bitmaps.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo unlink /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf # For disabling no-bitmap setting
```

Then do this to update settings

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Ubuntu 18.04, there seems to be no way to make all bitmap fonts available to font-config (therefore GUI applications), even one choose to use `70-force-bitmaps.conf`. Take Lucida for example:

```
$ ls -l 70*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep 23 11:38 70-force-bitmaps.conf -> ../conf.avail/70-force-bitmaps.conf
$ xlsfonts | grep -ci lucida
1200
$ fc-cache | grep -ci lucida
0
```

Even enabling it by name wouldn't work

```
$ cat 50-enable-lucida.conf
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <selectfont>
    <acceptfont>
      <pattern>
        <patelt name="family"><string>lucida</string></patelt>
      </pattern>
    </acceptfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
$ fc-cache | grep -ci lucida
0
```

`70-force-bitmpas.conf` still makes a select few fonts work - they are fixed, unifont, wqy-bitmap, all of them are typically used in xterm, where fixed is the main font and the other two are backup fonts to cover CJK character set.

It seems there is a progressive trend towards discouraging the use of bitmap fonts except in the occasion it can't be forgone - terminal emulators.

Answer (score 0):

> The fonts are visible with xfontsel but the app can't see/use them.

If you have enabled bitmap fonts in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` and updated font-cache with `sudo fc-cache -fv` but still not seeing the bitmap fonts in `fc-list` (therefore not seeing them in app's font selection), there is a possibility that the wrong font package was installed. For example, if you installed `xfonts-100dpi-transcoded` you will get a lot of PCF files and some of them are even big, but `xfonts-100dpi` is the package that provides fonts for font-config.